# Indexing an array with a string (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, caching

I have an array of unsigned integers, each corresponding to a string with 12 characters, that can contain 4 different characters, namely 'A','B','C','D'. Thus the array will contain 4^12 = 16777216 elements. The ordering of the elements in the array is arbitrary; I can choose which one corresponds to each string. So far, I have implemented this as simply as that:

```
unsigned int my_array[16777216];
char my_string[12];
int index = string_to_index(my_string);

my_array[index] = ...;
```

`string_to_index()` simply assigns 2 bits per character like this:
    A --> 00, B --> 01, C --> 10, D --> 11
For example, ABCDABCDABCD corresponds to the index (000110110001101100011011)<sub>2</sub> = (1776411)<sub>10</sub>

However, I know for a fact that each string that is used to access the array is the previous string shifted once to the left with a new last character. For example after I access with ABCDABCDABCD, the next access will use BCDABCDABCDA, or BCDABCDABCDB, BCDABCDABCDC, BCDABCDABCDD.

So my question is:
Is there a better way to implement the `string_to_index` function to take under consideration this last fact, so that elements that are consecutively accessed are closer in the array? I am hoping to improve my caching performance by doing so.

edit: Maybe I was not very clear: I am looking for a completely different string to index correspondence scheme, so that the indexes of ABCDABCDABCD and BCDABCDABCDA are closer.

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first. The question you asked is a lot more interesting than the one that I answered :-)

Comment: When you say 'improve my caching performance' what is your measurement- speed? memory consumption?

Comment: @Philip: He's referring to the CPU cache. Obviously the memory consumption will stay the same, but processing the data will be a lot faster if elements accessed closely in time are close in memory.

Comment: @PhilipAdler Speed is my main concern, but of course memory should be within reasonable bounds if needed to increase

Comment: Is this somehow a [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) optimization you are looking for ?

Comment: @Emilien Yes, it is almost that, but the "keeping the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again" part happens explicitly by the system's cache memory. I just want to enable it.

Comment: Can `string_to_index` be dependent on the previous string, or does it have to return the same result when called with the same string regardless of context?

Comment: @Cameron It has to return the same result every time. The array holds one value for each string, so when I encounter the string again, I can read the same value.

Comment: Note: In C, by definition §7.1.1, a "string" is an array of `char` up to and including the first `\0`.  This post uses the phrase "string" in a non-C context.  Better to consider `my_string` something like `my_char_array`.

Comment: Maybe `index = ((index << 2) | (my_string[12-1] & 3)) & 0xFFFFFF;`?

Comment: @cantfindname: I deleted the answer because it only solved the problem for a single call ie after one lookup in the array you get all four 'next possible values'. Apparently, you do not want to use your string to int function again..once you searched you expect all possible next values...recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following assumptions are true for your problem then the solution you implemented is best one.

1. The right most char of next string is randomly selected with equal probability for each valid character
2. Start of the sequence is not same always (it is random).

Reason:
When I first read your question I came up with the following tree: (reduced your problem to string of length three characters and only 2 possible characters A and B for simplicity) Note that left most child of root node (AAA in this case) is always same as root node (AAA) hence I am not building that branch further.

```
                      AAA
                     /  \
                        AAB       
                       /  \         
                     ABA    ABB
                    /  \    /   \ 
                 BAA   BAB  BBA  BBB
```

In this tree each node has its next possible sequence as child nodes. **To improve on cache you need to traverse this tree using breadth-first traversal and store it in the array in the same order.** For the above tree we get following string index combination.

- AAA 0
- AAB 1
- ABA 2
- ABB 3
- BAA 4
- BAB 5
- BBA 6
- BBB 7

Assuming value(A) = 0 and value(B) = 1, index can be calculated as

```
index = 2^0 * (value(string[2])) +  2^1 * (value(string[1])) + 2^2 * (value(string[0]))
```

This is same solution as you are using. 
I have written a python script to check this for other combinations too (like string of length 4 characters with A B C as possible characters). [Script link](https://gist.github.com/ravisutrave/d8ada8e08e93fad0b179)

So unless the 2 assumptions made at the beginning are false than your solution already takes care of cache optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I think we could define "closer" first.

For example, we could define a function F which takes a method of calculating the indices of strings. Then F will check every string's index and return a certain value based on the distance of neighbor strings' indices.

Then we can compare various ways of calculating the index and find a best one. 
Of course we could examine shorter strings first.